# Excel VBA Row Highlighting

Tags: excel, vba

I've found some examples of how to highlight the row of the currently selected cell. My issue is that I need to do this only in rows 3 and higher.

This is what I picked up so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    With Target
        .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works as advertised, but I am struggling with how to not lose the background color I have for header cells in rows 1 and 2. I am sure it requires an "if" of some sort, but I am not sure where I need to put it.

Also, is there anyway I can apply this to the entire workbook? I have 60 sheets in the workbook and if I can not replicate the code 60 times that would be ideal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do the trick:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Row <> 1 and Target.Row <> 2 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Range("A1:AF2").Interior.ColorIndex = 47
            Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
End Sub
```

you place this in `ThisWorkbook` instead of the specific `Sheet`.

the code:

```
If Target.Row <> 1 and Target.Row <> 2 Then
```

Checks if `Target.Row`  does not equal `Row 1 and 2`

Comment: This helps with only writing the code once against the workbook, but the line `Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0` still sets all rows to having no background color. Is it possible to set that Cells with a Range?

Comment: then which specific `Cell` do you wish to highlight, you don't mention this anywhere

Comment: Which `ColorIndex` does `Row 1 + 2` have?

Comment: I wish to highlight the entire row, based on the current selected cell. The code in it's current form removes color from all cells in the sheet, then applies the highlight to the selected row. Everything works fine, except that it removes the background color from rows 1 and 2. I am trying to keep that shading in place.

Comment: I do not know the exact index of rows 1 and 2, the color was chosen from the palette before I began modifying the sheet with VBA. Quick research, I'd guess it is 47.

Comment: @twfurst the entire row for 1 and 2?

Comment: If you are asking about the coloring of row 2, no. It currently runs from column A to AF.

Comment: You beat me to it, in a slightly different way. I just ran `Rows(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 47` and got the entire row. Thanks for helping, sometimes just need push in the right direction